# caching is not working in spring interceptor

Tags: caching, interceptor

I am using a interceptor to authenticate a user, i want that to be cacheable using Redis. Below is the code. The caching does not work inside the interceptor. the `@Cacheable` works in my controller i have tested that

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
    import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
    import uk.co.rullion.ledger.exception.UnauthorisedAccessException;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;


    @Component
    @Profile({"dev","prod"})
    public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws UnauthorisedAccessException {

            Map<String,List> userRoles = authenticateUser(username, password);
            ....

            return authorizationResult;
        }

        @Cacheable(value="authenticateUser")
        public Map<String,List> authenticateUser(String username, String password) {
            //authenticating user logic
// there service layer call is happening everytime
            return userRoles;
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only external method calls coming in through the proxy are
>   intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method
>   within the target object calling another method of the target object,
>   will not lead to an actual cache interception at runtime even if the
>   invoked method is marked with @Cacheable.

Extract the authenticateUser method call into an separate service and declare the class as @Service/@Component and the individual method will be cached using @cacheable annotation

Comment: spot on, extracting the method into a separate class solved the issue. Explanation given is satisfactory